# Difference between Iterables.tryFind and FluentIterable.firstMatch in Guava

Tags: java, guava

Is there any difference between?

```java
MyObject myWantedObj = Iterables.tryFind(myListOfObjects, new Predicate<MyObject>() {
    public boolean apply(MyObject myObj) {
        return myObj.getSomeAttribute().equals(someFinalVariable);
    }
}).orNull();
```

and

```java
MyObject myWantedObj = FluentIterable.from(myListOfObjects).firstMatch(new Predicate<MyObject>() {
    public boolean apply(MyObject myObj) {
        return myObj.getSomeAttribute().equals(someFinalVariable);
    }
}).orNull();
```

**[Iterables.tryFind](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#tryFind%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29)** and **[FluentIterable.firstMatch](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#firstMatch%28com.google.common.base.Predicate%29)** **Javadoc** are equals to:

> Returns an `Optional` containing the first element in iterable that satisfies the given predicate, if such an element exists.

I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Iterables.tryFind()` pre-dates `FluentIterable.firstMatch()` by quite a bit. If you're just doing a single operation (as in your example), it doesn't really matter which you use. We probably never would have created the `Iterables` class if we had created `FluentIterable` first (hindsight is 20/20).

The power of `FluentIterable` comes when you're chaining several functional-type steps together. For example:

```
   FluentIterable
       .from(database.getClientList())
       .filter(activeInLastMonth())
       .transform(Functions.toStringFunction())
       .limit(10)
       .toList();
```